# How to manage in-app-purchase for multiple users

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase

I have an app users can create groups with each other, and want to sell (via monthly subscription) premium groups with some extra features.

With in-app-purchase, admin of group can convert it to premium group. And i store that info at database like `groupstate: premium` or `groupstate: free`. Depending on that child group becomes premium or stills free.

So when admin cancels the subscription, with check on every app start I can get the subscription info, cancel the subscription and turn group state to free. But if admin never logs in; I cant check the subscription is valid or not and other users will be able to use premium.

What kind of structure do i need to avoid that ? Any suggestions ?